# Why is perfect tense used in this sentence?

Tags: usage, grammaticality, perfect-tense

I have a problem understanding the following sentence

> "Leider muss man manchmal lange suchen, bis man einen guten Kindergartenplatz gefunden hat"

This sentence appears in a textbook; but I think the main clause happens before the subordinate clause, then why using a perfect form in the subordinate clause?

Answer (score 4):

Main and subordinate clause can indeed be temporally independent.

> Ich **werde** in nächster Zeit mehr **arbeiten**, weil der Chef das **gefordert hat**.
>
> Ich **habe** in letzter Zeit viel **gearbeitet**, weil mir das **zugutekommen wird**.

But in the case of *bis*, there is no such independence: the event or state denoted by the *bis*-clause marks the termination of the event or state denoted by the main clause. Since the temporal relationship between the two clauses is fixed, the opposition between present and perfect can actually be neutralized. Both of the following are correct.

> Man muß lange suchen, bis man einen guten Platz **findet** / **gefunden hat**.

If the opposition is not neutralized, it can be repurposed to to make an aspectual distinction.

> Warte doch, bis wir **landen**. (=until landing begins)
>
> Warte doch, bis wir **gelandet sind**. (=until landing has finished)